# Facing NullPointerException while using Optional

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, java-8, option-type

I am using a `Map<String, Optional<List<String>>>`. I am getting an obvious `NullPointerException` because the result is `null` for that key.

Is there any way to handle the null situation?

```
public Map<MyEnum, Optional<List<String>>> process(Map<MyEnum, Optional<List<String>>> map) {
    Map<MyEnum, Optional<List<String>>> resultMap = new HashMap<>();
    // Getting NullPointerException here, since map.get(MyEnum.ANIMAL) is NULL
    resultMap.put(MyEnum.ANIMAL, doSomething(map.get(MyEnum.ANIMAL).get()));
    // do something more here
}

private Optional<List<String>> doSomething(List<String> list) {
    // process and return a list of String
    return Optional.of(resultList);
}
```

I am trying to avoid a `if-else` check for null by using Optional.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Map`'s `getOrDefault` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-).

> Returns the value to which the specified key is mapped, or `defaultValue` if this map contains no mapping for the key.

```
resultMap.put(MyEnum.ANIMAL,
    map.getOrDefault(MyEnum.ANIMAL, Optional.of(new ArrayList<>())) );
```

This avoids the `null` by having that method check for you.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out here.

Comment: I was also thinking of something like `map.getOrDefault(MyEnum.ANIMAL, Optional.empty()).flatMap(this::doSomething)...`. It was kind of ambiguous to me what the OP actually wanted to do in case that the mapping was not present, though.